# Image orientation mobile upload

Tags: php, android, orientation

I am implementing an image upload function to use the mobile phone camera.
It is working fine, but the photos are always rotated wrong.

I did read about using the php function exif_read_data.
I found codes how to use it and how to change the orientation and how to save it again. Now my problem is (using Android) that the exif_read_data array does not contain any "Orientation", so I am not able to change the orientation. I can not find any hints or posts about this problem. Why is my orientation not stored in this array?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem a few weeks ago, the only solution I found was to rotate the image accordingly before setting it up on the View. No need to touch stuff related to orientation. Once I used this function, I uploaded my image to Firebase and everything was cool.

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap sourceBitmap, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Use this function to set it to your ImageView in this case:

```
if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA_PHOTO) {
            imgURL = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imgURL);
                bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, -90);
                ivProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, will this be rotating all photos? Even photos I choose from the phones galerie? Because When I upload a photo from the galerie it shows correctly.

Comment: You choose when to call this function, in the above case when I require the camera - I need to rotate my photos. From what I recall, I used to apply this function only to the camera situation, but when I upload from gallery the picture wasn't rotated initially so I didn't have to rotate the Bitmap to get it to its normal state. Just apply the function for the camera photos and for the galley ones don't.